# Does this pin Claudia wears have any significance?

Tags: reference, the-americans

After rewatching the TV series, *The Americans*, I started to notice that in later seasons, such as seasons 5 & 6 the recurring character Claudia (Margo Martindale), who serves as the Jenkins *on again and off again* KGB Handler, is often shown wearing a pin or broach of two squirrels playing/fighting over a nut.

[image: Claudia season 6]

I can easily speculate that Claudia's choice in pins or broaches is part of her cover in wanting to look like a kind older lady and/or that the squirrels 'fighting over the nut' is a kind of 'quirky' metaphor for the Cold War/Nuclear Arms Race, but outside of those two things,

**I was wondering if there was any other significance to this particular broach? Is there something else I am failing to see that perhaps relates to her character more personally or the KGB?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The brooches were indeed picked for a reason and it *does* have something to do with Russia. From [StyleCaster's interview](https://stylecaster.com/the-americans-fx/) with the show's costume designer, Jenny Gering:

> For those viewers with an eye for any conspiratorial details, look to the wardrobe of Claudia, the couple’s KGB supervisor.
>   **“Margo [Martindale, the actress] and I decided she would have a collection of brooches. I chose the squirrel as it’s a very symbolic animal in Russia.** A little nod to her ancestors.”

Martindale herself [elaborated in The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/05/margo-martindale/371326/):

> I did know last year what my personal life was. I had in my head how I lived, what kind of life I had. **I even travel with one little collection of things that I brought from the homeland. One collection is squirrels. Squirrel pins. Every time you see me I’m wearing a squirrel pin. The idea came from Jenny [Gering], the costume designer. We talked about how wildly fun it would be.** Because I talked about *Justified* and things I had decided that made the character, inspired me. Why did I wear a belt around my waist? What kind of shoes I had on? All these things I brought, but I kind of created with the designer. And Jenny and I did that with these squirrel things. And maybe I should have kept it a secret, but **I collect squirrels. They are a symbol of something good in Russia.** So check it out. I’m always wearing a squirrel.